# Data.Either.Validation monoid implementation, ok+error=ok?

Tags: validation, haskell, monoids

I look at this:

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/either-5.0.1.1/docs/Data-Either-Validation.html

implementation of monoid:

```
instance Monoid e => Monoid (Validation e a) where
  mempty = Failure mempty
  Failure e1 `mappend` Failure e2 = Failure (e1 `mappend` e2)
  Failure _  `mappend` Success a2 = Success a2
  Success a1 `mappend` Failure _  = Success a1
  Success a1 `mappend` Success _  = Success a1
```

I expect that success with error must be merged to error...
and can't understand why it implemented in such a way that
success with error merged to success?

So if I have a bunch of validation results and one of them is failed I expect to reduce all to fail, with merging all errors.

but:

```
Prelude Data.Either.Validation> Success 1 `mappend` Failure ["er1"] `mappend` Failure ["er2"]
Success 1
```

why?

comes to mind, if I have several validation results and if one of them pass - then total validation ok.. for such cases? for, example if I validate that contact is email or skype or phone, one of them valid, then it's ok?

Comment: "and one of them is failed I expect to reduce all to fail" but this is already the `Applicative` behaviour, which you can leverage over a any `Traversable` container (like lists) by using the `traverse` function.

Comment: ok, but for monoids this logic that ok+fail=ok, there can be useful..?

Comment: comes to mind, if I have several validation results and if one of them pass - then total validation ok.. for such cases?

Comment: @Evg: a monoid has a single neutral element `e` (in Haskell `mempty`). This means that ``e `mappend` x`` is `x` and ``x `mappend` e`` is `x`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, thnx.., it seem's monoid structure dictate implmentation here.., and we can't change "mempty = Failure mempty" to "mempty = Success mempty", this need Monoid a => ...

Comment: `Validation` is similar to `First` (a monoid wrapper around `Maybe`), in that `Nothing <> Nothing == Nothing`.